# Dimensions of a QR Code printed on a floor decal?

Tags: qr-code

I am looking to put a QR Code on a floor decal in a grocery store.  We are going to encode the URL to a promotion micro-site.

What should the dimensions of the QR Code be for it to be read correctly?

Comment: The dimensions don't really matter, as long as they are of a reasonable size.  Take a cell phone and turn on its camera.  If that QR code can fill 1/4th of the view, then that is plenty.  Likewise, don't make it bigger than you can fit in the view when a short person holding the phone is standing above it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing why there is a need for there to be any explicit dimensions; the required elements of a QR code are used to determine size, alignment, etc. As long as you're printing a actually valid QR code (border included, etc), the customer should be able to adjust the focal distance from the camera to the code.

If you're really so inclined, just hold an average smartphone at average-person height, and roughly determine the size from the field of view.

Comment: I agree.  The amount of information to be encoded determines the size (aka area) of the QR code (http://goo.gl/Cl38u).  The client/designer would like to keep it as small as possible to not distract from the decal's creative content.  But, I need to make sure that it is an effective size for a reader to understand it without having to kneel down to capture it.

Comment: I took your advice and gen'd a QR code and scaled it to 4x4, 6x6 and 8x8.  I had to get very close to the 4x4.  I can to bend over but not uncomfortably to read the 6x6.  And the 8x8 had the same result as the 6x6.  So we went with the 6x6 to lessen the area required.